# Using MDM alternative after apples MDM block

Tags: ios, development, mobile-device-management

How can I create an app that can track location, regulate screen time by blocking access without using MD? What are some alternate ways of doing this after Apple has blocked the use of MDM  feature.

Answer (score 1):

There are no alternate ways. Apple has not blocked the use of MDM, you can use that still. However, you must abide by the terms and conditions of using MDM. For example you use it to control your own devices - not to control the devices of others.

Answer (score 0):

Ask people to install your app and opt in to location sharing, disclosing what you do and why is the best plan for 2020.

Same with screen time. Ask them to comply or use family sharing if your target group is small enough.

Watch here for more options in the future if things change on the MDM front: https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/welcome/web